# How to move Ubuntu SDK data?

Tags: ubuntu-sdk

I have a very small partition where `/` is installed (on an SSD).

I would like to start programming something for Ubuntu Phone via the SDK.

Unfortunately I do not have enough space to install the necessary "Kit" to program for the `armhf` architecture (my disk fill up and then the installation of the kit fails).

So, how can I tell to Ubuntu SDK to move these data (the ones linked to the chroots that it makes) to somewhere else?

I could also use some symlinks and manually move the folders, but I do not know which they are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking carefully at the outputs from `du` and similar tools, I discovered that the big directory is `/var/lib/schroot`.

So I moved it to another place

```
sudo mv /var/lib/schroot ~/Dati/SDK
```

and the symlinked it

```
sudo ln -s ~/Dati/SDK/schroot /var/lib/
```

Until now, it works.